# What is the difference between Django and Html?

Tags: html, django

I am fairly new to Django and would like to know how  Django is  different from html?

Comment: Django is a framework you use to help you generate html.

Comment: I guess you need to read more on client and server before doing anything related to web.

Comment: If you mean templates, in simple terms, django templates has something like placeholders which can be dynamically populated with information. It's more complex because you have conditionals, loops. Read on [tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/) to get an idea

Comment: Why the downvote ? This is a very serious question, the person asked it correctly with proper title, content and syntax. Just because it's a very beginer question should not implies downvoting.

Comment: @user3037128 : I apologize for the behavior of the other commenters. This is not usually the way stackoverflow works. You can keep asking such questions, it's fine.

Comment: @e-satis, the hover text on the downvote button says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". While it may be clear, it does not show very much research effort.

Comment: How can you assess that ? How can you tell he (or she) didn't try and fail because he coudln't search properly as he didn't has nor the concept or the vocabulary required to make the right queries or analyses from the results. Such assumptions is not only very pretentious, but also very agressive and will turn newbies away. Also, it's no like his questions cost you anything, and surely, the answer to it will help others in his situation later.

Comment: Plus I'm pretty sure the search is supposed to be about similar questions in SO, not around the Web. It's it the purpose of SO to exactly list the aswers to these kind of questions, as well as others.

Comment: @e-satis, certainly, we should try to be welcoming. I'm just trying to answer your question about why downvotes may have been cast on this question. Stack Overflow advocates [thoroughly researching on SO and elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) before asking a question, and [specifically describes the types of questions not to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**HTML is a language used to make Web pages.**

When you "go online", you in fact use a software called a Web browser, downloading a code. This code is then used to display the Web pages : the color, the text, the images and so on.

HTML is a part of this code. It's the code saying "this information is a title, this information is a paragraph, this is an image", etc.

**Django is a tool to generate Web pages**

It can do more than that, but's that the basics of it. Writting HTML code by hand is very tedious, not very efficient, and limited : you can't make pages that adapts to the person who asks for it such as a user page or a search page.

Django is a tool that can understand what a user is asking, and create the HTML code in a fraction of a second, then send it back. When you see a Website such as Google or Amazon, they are using such a tool to display what you search for (although they don't use Django, there are many similar tools to do so).

If you want to learn to make Web sites with Django, you probably want to learn things in that order :

1. HTML : you can make static web sites with it
2. CSS : you make you web site prettier with advanced layouts
3. Python (the language used in Django) : you can automate things with it
4. Django : you can automatically create web pages with it
5. Javascript : make your web pages more interactive

It's a pretty long process, so be sure that's what you need. If you just want a blog or an e-commerce web site, there are plenty already made solutions that exist and don't require to know programming.