# How do you use Django in Python to make html/css framework much faster?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I've done very tedious task for html and css alone to make pH barometer, but I found out Python Django has a function to do this within a fraction of seconds. How do you do that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Color</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background-color: silver;
                color: white;
                padding: 20px;
                font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;}
            h1 {
                background-color: #fffffff;
                background-color: hsla(0,100%,100%,0.5);
                color: #64645A;
                padding: inherit;}
            p {
                padding: 5px;
                margin: 0px;}
            p.zero{
                background-color: rgb(238,62,128);}
            p.one {
                background-color: rgb(244,90,139);}
            p.two {
                background-color: rgb(243,106,152);}
            p.three {
                background-color: rgb(244,123,166);}
            p.four {
                background-color: rgb(245,140,178);}
            p.five {
                background-color: rgb(245,159,192);}
            p.six {
                background-color: rgb(245,176,204);}
            p.seven {
                background-color: rgb(0,187,136);}
            p.eight {
                background-color: rgb(140,202,242);}
            p.nine {
                background-color: rgb(114,193,240);}
            p.ten {
                background-color: rgb(84,182,237);}
            p.eleven {
                background-color: rgb(48,170,233);}
            p.thirteen {
                background-color: rgb(0,160,230);}
            p.fourteen {
                background-color: rgb(0,136,221);}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>pH Scale</h1>
        <p class="fourteen">14.0 VERY ALKALINE</p>
```

From this source [What is the difference between Django and Html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21582300/what-is-the-difference-between-django-and-html)

What function or setting do I have to find in Django to make any framework of html/css within a fraction of seconds since html and css alone to make such framework is hugely tedious task?

Comment: That linked question doesn't make much sense and your question is not very clear either. Are you trying to generate CSS using Python code instead of hand coding it or are you asking something else?

Comment: Should be possible to do this in pure Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You have many solutions available. For example, in your case, you can create a template tag to generate the CSS in your base.html template that produces you the CSS using a `for`.

Have a look at this example on how to create a simple tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags

The problem and you didn't add details on your answer, is to get the data to create the RGB values. If the RGB is related to the model you are rendering in your template, you can use the `inline style CSS`

The last solution can be completed using a template tag that can render your object with CSS style based on the data in the object.

```
@register.inclusion_tag('element.html')
def render_element(element *args, **kwargs):

    context = {}
    # here based on your element you can decide what to add 
    # in the context. You can also create `inline css` that your
    # template will render as you want.
    ...
    return context
```

See the details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags

Your problem is strictly a rendering problem so I would avoid involving the model.

Answer (score -1):

Well I don't know of a single function to make pH barometer colors, but if you're looking for some sort of framework to make CSS styles quicker, maybe you'd like to look at Bootstrap first. It is a quick sort of plugin that can make your application look pretty quickly, and it comes with a lot of special CSS styles that you can implement much quicker.

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp

Also, you may want to think about making a seperate style sheet for your CSS.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial06/